# Using chocolatey and invoke-command on a remote share

Tags: chocolatey, invoke-command

I am trying to use invoke-command to install some chocolatey packages.

When the files are embedded in the chocolatey package, it works without problems. However, when I try to specify a share on a remote server and even opening it in read/write for everyone, I get an access denied when chocolatey try to access it.

Ironically, if I do the same command on the target computer and not using invoke-command, it works like a charm!

Is there something I am not getting?

The powershell script is standard:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\ladmin\Desktop\testpowershell\vm3.txt"
$Cred = Get-Credential $env:USERNAME


foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {
        $Computer
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {choco install ue-4.24-zip -my -t=0}
    }
```

And here is my chocoinstall script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; # stop on all errors
$fileLocation = '\\testserver\test\UE_4.24.zip'
Install-ChocolateyZipPackage $packageName $fileLocation -UnzipLocation "c:\test"
```

I really don't get what I am doing wrong.....

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely be experiencing the "douple hop problem".

See

- [Making the second hop in PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop)
- [Safely running windows automation operations that fail inside winrm or powershell remoting](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/safely-running-windows-automation-operations-that-typically-fail-over-winrm-or-powershell-remoting)

You have a couple of different ways to resolve this problem, such as setting up CredSSP, Kerberos constraint delgation, JEA, or the 'simplest' solution: just pass a PSCredentials object to the Invoke-Command script block you're using to install the Chocolatey packages and use these to setup the required network resources.

I'd suggest you look into [Boxstarter](https://boxstarter.org/) for deploying Chocolatey packages to remote hosts.